# I was refused a Canada visitor visa because I didn't attend the Biometrics appointment and I'll apply for UK visa, is that OK?

Tags: visas, uk, canada, visa-refusals

I didn't attend the Biometrics appointment for personal reasons, so I got refusal letter and I sent a message to them explain my reason but they said the final decision is made and you can't do anything, and now I'm planning to apply for the UK visa and on my application they ask me if I was refused from any country, what I should do about that? is there any impact on UK visa application result?

Comment: It's not part of the question, but you caused yourself a lot of trouble by simply not showing up to the Biometrics appointment. It would have been much better to have withdrawn the visa application if you knew you were not going to attend the interview.

Answer (score 3):

You should answer the questions on your UK application truthfully. i.e. Answer that you were refused a Canadian visa. There will be space somewhere in the application form for you to explain your reasons. If not, add a covering letter with the explanation.

This may have an effect on your UK application, or it may not. It depends on the reasons you have for missing the biometrics appointment and how you present them.